# What is the CronTriggeringPolicy priority?

Tags: spring, cron, log4j2

I have a cron schedule that runs log writing every hour.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
```

And every hour I use Log4j2's CronTriggeringPolicy to roll the logs up to the previous day.

```
CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"
```

At this time, the question is, if the time of cron rolling the log and cron leaving the log are the same,

Which one works first?

The way I want it to work is that the rolling is done first, and a new log is written.

In my experiments, rolling is the first thing that happens, but I don't know if it's a coincidence or what the system intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")` triggers at 00:00:00 every day. The hourly schedule is defined as `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * ?")`.

Second, the `@Scheduled` implementation in Spring and `CronTriggeringPolicy` in Log4j are completely separate and unrelated implementations of the same concept so what you experience is most likely a coincidence.

One way to achieve the determined ordering of schedules could be shifting either of them by some amount from the hour start, e.g. `@Scheduled(cron = "1 0 * * * ?")` which will trigger at the first second of every hour allowing time for the daily log rollover to perform.